# modal window in rails after create action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, modal-dialog

So, I want to show a modal message after I create an event or an user in my website, or after editing something, so far I just know how to use flash to show small messages, but I'd like to know how to do this with modal windows, and that they only show up after a certain method in the controller is used, exactly like a flash message, but in a modal window.

I've looked into the matter and have found `format.html` and `format.js`
seem to do the trick however I'm kinda lost on how to properly use them.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for js response. The best way to start and understand the flow is to follow the rails guides 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use an instance variable like @ObjectCreated and access it in the view.erb file,  and do something like

<% if @objectCreated %> 
  insert html for modal 
<% end %>.

then assuming your page refreshes use a dom loaded javascript function to open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you already have modal html.

```
<% if flash[:event] == true %>
   <script>$(function() { $('#modal-id'}.modal('show'); });</script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

if you have modal in a partial then render it in your view:

`<%= render 'your_partial' %>`

and then:

```
`<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
      });
    </script>
<% end %>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try the complete solution

**Step 1**

Create a partial `layouts/_modal.html.erb`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alert</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="container"> 
                     <div class="row"> 
                          <div class="col-md-12"> 
                              <div class="alert-message <%="#{name}" %>-message">
                                  <p><%= msg %></p>
                                  <i class="icofont icofont-close"></i>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 2**

Then controller to create or update action

```
flash[:success] = 'Category was successfully created.'
OR
flash[:danger] = 'Ooops! something went wrong'
```

**Step 3**

On the `layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= render partial: "layouts/modal" %>
<% end %>
```

**Step 4**

On the footer

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

Or you can use that in the flash section or external JS file

This is tested and working perfectly

Hope it helps